# svn: E120108: Unable to connect to SVN repo

Tags: svn, repository

I recently replaced the hard drive of my Mac so I reinstalled SVN. But I can't connect to the repository, and the errors are:

```
svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'xxxxxx'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

I can access the URL in browser. SVN is also installed correctly. When I type `svn --version` it shows that I have `SVN 1.8.3`.

Has anyone seen the same problem before. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the command you are using to contact the repository?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke, `brew install v8` in my case

Answer (score 6):

The removal of the auth folders did not work for me but I resolved a similar issue by using the https protocol in the URL as opposed to http (though the browser displays with the latter). Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a DNS A/AAAA Records addresses to ipv6.
I remove the ipv6 address and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a recent install of SVN version 1.8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system.

Clearing out the saved authentication files and just re-authenticating fixed the issue for me. I deleted all the files with hashed names underneath the C:\Users[My User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth[authentication type]\ directories. The next time I ran SVN, it prompted me for my credentials and updated without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, firewall of antivirus program block this access. So change the network traffic filtering or turn off firewall (not recommend).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same issue with a recent install of SVN version 1.8.10 on a Linux Server. Type these commands:

```
svnserve
```

This starts the svn service.

```
svn checkout svn:url 'XXXXXX'
```

Use your check out functionality to checkout the code from your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another fix. Seems to be related to serf. Add this line to your `~/.subversion/servers` file (you can try it in the `[global]` section, but I wouldn't recommend leaving out on for all your connections:

```
[global]
http-chunked-requests = no
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions listed here did not work for me but bobbogo's answer put me in the correct area.

Basically in ~/.subversion/servers I discovered the following

```
[global]
http-proxy-host= www-my-repo-address.com
```

Not sure how that setting got there. Cornorstone is installed on the machine maybe it modified it (but that's a guess).

Once the *http-proxy-host* setting was commented out the issue was resolved and the code could be checked out. i.e.

```
[global]
#http-proxy-host= www-my-repo-address.com
```

Note: I experienced this issue with both svn 1.7 and 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from that exact error on Windows 10 for more than half a year, I think.
Finally, was able to resolve this today.
Haven't found this particular suggestion anywhere on SO, thus sharing with you guys! :)

First, a few details to add.
The problem was REALLY intermittent: sometimes worked OK, sometimes any command worked on the second run only.
That was somewhat OK during months, since I do not use SVN much (mainly use Git last years), but some of my side projects still have to use it, and a few days back I needed to `svn up` one of my workspaces when... 100 out of 100 attempts failed! (I executed it in a loop `for /L %i in (1,1,100) do svn up & PowerShell -Command "get-date"` just to test and collect the statistics).
I remember I did the same months back (when first experienced the issue) and the result was around 80% failed.

Googling the error again didn't help at all.

Changing the client didn't help as well (I tried with **Subversion 1.8.17** and **TortoiseSVN 1.9.7** and **1.12.0**).
Btw, in Tortoise the first error code is a bit different:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'xxxxxx'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

.
So, this time it blocked my work, and I dived right into finally resolving this today by reading number of docs and doing some more research and web surfing, eventually I came to this page: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_subversion_to_trust_a_given_ssl_certificate.html

And, voila!
Adding the following line into my `C:\Users\RAM237\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers` fixed it once and for all:

```
ssl-authority-files = D:\Path\to\my\rootCA.pem
```

.
Funny thing, I haven't had such issues earlier when using various Linux svn clients or same Tortoise SVN on Windows 8.
It turned out, the company, siting this repo, switched to cert-based connection around the time I changed the OS :)

Hope this could be helpful for lost souls :D